# Why AJAX sends more than one cookie?

Tags: express, cookies, session-cookies, express-session

I have an aplication running on ExpressJS handling session with "express-session" on mongo store. When i make a regular http request with the browser for loading a page getting i can see the correct cookie on the server as:

```
console.log(req.headers.cookie) // connect.sid=s%3ABC....
```

The problem raises when, on the same page, i make an AJAX call and on the server i see something like this:

```
console.log(req.headers.cookie) // connect.sid=s%3DEF; connect.sid=s%3GHI; connect.sid=s%3ABC
```

So it seems like AJAX sends old cookies with the same name on the request resulting in the server adding the data to a wrong session..

On the first request the cookie is being set as follows:

```
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3ABC...; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 20 Jun 2018 19:40:59 GMT; HttpOnly
```

Any ideas how can this be happening?

Comment: what is your cookie path in node app ?

Comment: cookie path is set to "/"